# Runtime Type Casting

Tags: c#, winforms, events, casting

**Scenario**

Within a panel (say panel-1) when I click a button from a range of buttons, buttons are displayed in another panel (say panel-2).

When a button in panel-2 is clicked it should display a custom control (for every button click there is different custom control which I want to display).

The 'Name' property of all buttons in panel-2 contains the type of my custom control (retrieved from Database).

Thats how my implementation goes for button click event in panel-2:

```
    public void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonItem btnAtomic = sender as ButtonItem;

            if (btnAtomic != null)
            {
                Type type = Type.GetType(btnAtomic.Name, true, true);
                object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                type.GetProperty("Dock")
                    .SetValue(obj, DockStyle.Fill, null);

                  // following is the line where I'm stuck:
                    panel3.Controls.Add((*Runtime Type*)obj);
                  //
            }
            else
            {
                // log custom error tht its not a buttonItem
            }

    }
```

**Question**

How can I convert type of 'obj' at runtime depending upon the button clicked in panel-2?

I can't use:

```
Convert.ChangeType<T>();
```

I'm thinking for the above to work the event should also be generic, something like:

```
public void BtnClick<T>(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Is that even possible?
Is there any other way can get the type at runtime to cast the 'obj' accordingly?

**Don't Need**

I know It can be solved through Switch statement with ample case statement checking for the right type which doesn't look elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting is a compile time thing, you are instructing the compiler to ignore the fact that `obj` is declared as `object` because you as a developer know that it is really a form control. However all form controls share a base type, you can just cast to that `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. There is a similar base control for web forms and wpf.

Comment: In my code I replaced: panel3.Controls.Add((*Runtime Type*)obj); by panel3.Controls.Add((System.Windows.Forms.Control)obj); as suggested. Thanks Ben!